# The conditions of a metric to be geodesically complete

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

On $\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R^n}:x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2<1\}$ in $\mathbb {R^n},$ what $\alpha$ can make the metric
$$g=(1-x_1^2-x_2^2-\cdots-x_n^2)^{-\alpha}(dx_1\otimes dx_1+dx_2\otimes dx_2+\cdots+dx_n\otimes dx_n)$$complete?

I guess this is related to the [Hopf-Rinow theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem), but I fail to solve it. Looking forward to your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A natural first step would be to prove that the geodesics through $0$ are exactly the straight lines through $0$. Then Hopf-Rinow says that $B$ is complete if and only if any straight line segment from $0$ to $S^{n-1} = \{x\in R^n : \|x\| = 1\}$ has infinite length. Thus if $\|x\| = 1$, you must see whether or not the path $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to R^n$ given by $\gamma(t) = tx$ has infinite length. The length of $\gamma$ is $$\int_0^1 \|\gamma'(t)\|\,dt = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{(1 - t^2)^{\alpha/2}}.$$ This integral converges if and only if $\alpha<2$. Thus $B$ should be complete if and only if $\alpha\geq 2$.

**Edit:**
In response to the question of how we know the geodesics through $0$ are the straight lines. One should suspect this is the case upon observing that the metric under consideration is *radially symmetric*. In particular, reflections through hyperplanes through the origin are isometries, and hence preserve geodesics. We will use this fact.

Suppose that $\vec{v}$ is a tangent vector at $0$, and let $\gamma$ be the geodesic in the direction of $\vec{v}$. Let $H$ be any hyperplane through $0$ containing the line through $\vec{v}$. If $r_H\colon B\to B$ is the reflection through $H$, it is an isometry, and hence $\gamma = \gamma\circ r_H$. It follows that $\gamma$ is contained in $H$. But this is true for every hyperplane $H$ through $0$ containing the line through $\vec{v}$, and hence $\gamma$ lies in the intersection of all such $H$. The intersection of all such $H$ is of course the line through $\vec{v}$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks. What does "$0$" mean in your answer? The origin? And, why does "Hopf-Rinow say that $B$ is complete if and only if any straight line segment from $0$ to $S^{n-1}$ has infinite length"? Where does "infinite" come from?

Comment: "0" does mean the origin, sorry. You can use the Hopf-Rinow theorem to see the geodesic has to have infinite length in two different ways. 1) If the $\gamma$ has infinite length, then the exponential map at $0$ is defined on the whole tangent space, since geodesics starting at $0$ can never "leave" the space $B$. 2) If the $\gamma$ has infinite length, this shows that the balls $\overline{B}(0,R) = \{x : d(x,0)\leq R\}$ is bounded away from $\partial B$, and thus is compact. It follows that all closed and bounded sets are compact.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't know why "the geodesics through $0$ are exactly the straight lines through $0$". Could you explain it?

Comment: @Jack Witt: I edited my answer to give a reason for this. Hope it helps!